# Reading Notepad into array - BlueJ

Tags: java, arrays, notepad, bluej

So I'm creating a program that makes random words. Now, I have a Notepad file with roughly 58000 words, all in different lines. I want the entire notepad file, each line read into an element of a dictionary array that will be used to check each word against itself, so that the words, at the least, make sense.
Here is my coding so far, I'm only a beginner at Java, and use BlueJ.

```
import java.io.*;

class autosentence {
    public static void main() throws IOException {
        System.out.print('\f');
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        String a[] = new String[x];
        char c;
        int b[] = new int[3];
        String str;
        for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                a[i] = "";
                b[0] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
                for (int j = 0; j < b[0]; j++) {
                    b[1] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
                    if (b[1] < 4) {
                        b[2] = 65;
                    } else if (b[1] < 7) {
                        b[2] = 70;
                    } else if (b[1] < 10) {
                        b[2] = 80;
                    } else {
                        b[2] = 90;
                    }
                    if (b[2] < 90) {
                        c = (char) ((int) ((Math.random() * 10) + b[2]));
                    } else {
                        c = 'Z';
                    }
                    a[i] += c;
                }
            }
            for (int l = 0; l < x; l++) {
                System.out.print(a[l] + " ");
            }
            str = in.readLine();
            if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                str = "";
                k--;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I want a[i] to be checked against say 
    String dt[]=new String[58000]

Comment: I know that BlueJ is fairly basic, but does it have an autoformat function? Please, please use it. This code is illegible.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. It will read your txt file into arraylist and will return the result as an arraylist of all words.

```
public static ArrayList<String> readData(String fileName) throws Exception
  {
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    String temp = in.readLine(); 
    while (temp != null)
    {
        data.add(temp);
        temp = in.readLine();
    }
    in.close();
    return data;
  }
```

after having this method in your code, you can have following code to compare words.

```
ArrayList<String> allWordsFromNotepad = readData("your file name");
boolean wordExist = false;
for (String s : allWordsFromNotepad)
    { if (s.equals("variable name of your random word"))
        { wordExist = true
         } }
```

Your wordExist variable will hold the status if the word exist in the current notepad list or not. If the word exist, the status will be true else false.

Hope it will help.